# WooCommerce: Return widget on category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm quite new in PHP and im strugle with my WooCommerce shop. I'd like to return specific widget right at the top of product category page.

I add widget with this code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[widget id="woof_widget-7"]'); ?>
```

and now im strugle with return it at the top of product category page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found answer ;) 
I simply add

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
        echo do_shortcode('[widget id="woof_widget-7"]'); ?>
```